# Laravel, composer install, don't install laravel/framework

Tags: php, laravel, installation, composer-php

Need Laravel expert to help me figure out what is wrong with my composer.json configuration. I googled for answers and follow along and aldo I check every possible line, I still can get this to work. I got these files from git repo and it works in the office, but when I tried to do the same thing at home, this happend.

The error I am getting is:

```
  Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.45
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.44
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.43
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.42
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.41
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.40
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.39
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.38
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.37
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.36
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.35
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.34
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.33
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.32
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.31
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.30
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.29
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.28
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.27
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.26
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.25
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.24
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.23
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.22
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.21
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.20
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.19
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.18
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.17
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.16
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.15
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.14
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.13
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.3
- Installation request for orangehill/iseed dev-master -> satisfiable by orangehill/iseed[dev-master].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.1
- orangehill/iseed dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.3.8 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.16, v5.3.23].
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.1.0
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.10, v5.1.11, v5.1.12, v5.1.13, v5.1.14, v5.1.15, v5.1.16, v5.1.17, v5.1.18, v5.1.19, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.21, v5.1.22, v5.1.23, v5.1.24, v5.1.25, v5.1.26, v5.1.27, v5.1.28, v5.1.29, v5.1.3, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.32, v5.1.33, v5.1.34, v5.1.35, v5.1.36, v5.1.37, v5.1.38, v5.1.39, v5.1.4, v5.1.40, v5.1.41, v5.1.42, v5.1.43, v5.1.44, v5.1.45, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9].
```

And here is my composer.json:

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0",
    "intervention/image": "^2.3",
    "laracasts/flash": "~1.3",
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*",
    "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^3.1",
    "kyslik/column-sortable": "~5.0.0",
    "propaganistas/laravel-phone": "~2.0",
   "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.0.*",
    "caouecs/laravel-lang": "~3.0",
    "dimsav/laravel-translatable": "^6.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager": "0.2.3",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "orangehill/iseed": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files" : [
        "app/Helpers/helpers.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Comment: Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework ☺

Answer (score 6):

Just remove this dependency from your compose.json if you want to use Laravel 6 or above

```
laravelcollective/html
```

and then run composer update in your terminal

```
composer update
```

Comment: That's all needed, error message could have mentioned that

Comment: There is no such thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using lower version of laravel like 5.7.2 and your package needs 5.7.7
then try this:

```
composer require laravel/framework
```

Comment: Please share more details - `laravel/framework` is already listed in the set of required packages. Requiring it again will not solve the given error message

Answer (score 2):

Update `composer.json` file to install latest Laravel version. You need to update the php version for that as well.

```
"laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
"php": ">=5.6.4",
```

**Update**

Since you don't want to install the latest Laravel version. From the error log -

> orangehill/iseed dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.3.8

This is under `require-dev`. Therefore you try `composer install --no-dev` which won't install the plugins under `require-dev`. Those plugins mostly use for application testing.

Comment: I cannot install 5.3 because my application will crash, it would take days to configure it to 5.3 :(

Comment: @RadomirAntic Updated the answer. Please check

Comment: Thanks Saumini, I actually deleted the orangehill/iseed package, and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not previously installed packages, the package.json file and composer add-ons need the composer install command, not composer update command.

```
composer install
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? I don't understand how your answer relates to the question

Comment: According to the question here, the user changed computers, if the packages in the package.json file have never been installed on the new computer, it means that the command ''composer update'' will return the error presented in the question. For this reason, it is necessary to run ''composer install'' and not ''composer update ''.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear, the relevant lines are:

```
- Installation request for orangehill/iseed dev-master -> satisfiable by orangehill/iseed[dev-master].
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.1.1
- orangehill/iseed dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.3.8 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.3.16, v5.3.23].
```

The package `orangehill/iseed` requires Laravel v5.3, but your `composer.json` is configured to use Laravel v5.1. Either upgrade your application such that it can use Laravel v5.3, or use any older version of `orangehill/iseed` that is compatible with Laravel v5.1